# Category name not appearing on backend

Tags: magento2, category

I am using Magento ver. 2.4.4.
Facing issue with category.
The category names are not appearing in name field on backend.
How to fix this issue?
[image]

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: check in your database that the name is stored or not.
SELECT  * FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` where attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM `eav_entity_type` where entity_type_code = 'catalog_category') and attribute_code = 'name');

Answer (score 0):

Make sure with your database that category name is stored or not.

Execute below query it would help for find out.

```
SELECT entity_type_id FROM `eav_entity_type` where entity_type_code =
     'catalog_category';
```

And

```
select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM `eav_entity_type` where entity_type_code = 'catalog_category') and attribute_code = 'name';
```

check in **catalog_category_entity_varchar** table.

```
SELECT  * FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` where attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM `eav_entity_type` where entity_type_code = 'catalog_category') and attribute_code = 'name');
```

If above query return result with proper name, You should check in code.

Before test clean cache and do re-indexing.